Simple question about iterating inequality to achieve second inequality
In this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8378), it states:

You don't need to know the context here: I only need help seeing how iterating the first inequality leads to the second one. I tried using the first inequality over and over again starting with $m(n, J_k)$ but that didn't work out well – if we start with this, we assume that $2^{2k} n = n$, or that $k = 0$. But we obviously can't work with $J_0$ here. I'm not sure how to "iterate" the inequality then to get the desired inequality.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

what is $f$ here?

@vallev f is a function. However, you don’t need to know that part. I only need to understand how iterating $m(2^{2k}n, J_k) \leq 2^{2k-2}m(n, J_k) + 2k2^{8k}n$ leads to $m(n, J_k) \leq 3k2^{8k}$.

You are correct, it was not needed except to prove the first inequality. I included a template for the iterated substitution as an answer.

Start with the inequality:
$m(2^{2k}n, J_k) \leq 2^{2k-2} m(n, J_k) + 2k 2^{8k} n$
Apply the inequality to $m(n, J_k)$:
$m(n, J_k) \leq 2^{2k-2} m(n/2^{2k}, J_k) + 2k 2^{8k} n$
Substitute this into the first inequality:
$m(2^{2k}n, J_k) \leq 2^{2k-2}(2^{2k-2} m(n/2^{2k}, J_k) + 2k 2^{8k}n) + 2k 2^{8k}n$
$m(2^{2k}n, J_k) \leq 2^{2(2k-2)} m(n/2^{2k}, J_k) + 2k 2^{8k}n + 2^{2k-2} 2k 2^{8k}n$
Repeat this process:
$m(2^{2k}n, J_k) \leq 2^{2(2k-2j)} m(n/2^{4k}, J_k) + \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 2^{2k-2j} 2k 2^{8k}n$
Sum the geometric series:
$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 2^{2k-2j} 2k 2^{8k}n = 2k 2^{8k}n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \cdots \right) = \frac{4}{3} 2k 2^{8k}n$
Final bound:
$m(n, J_k) \leq \frac{4}{3} 2k 2^{8k}n + m(2^{2k}, J_k) \leq 3k 2^{8k}$
